# How to write a Realm Results object extension

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols, extension-methods, realm

I want write an extension that simplifies a complex filtering on my `Results` object. I tried this:

```
extension Results where T:MyProtocol {
    func filterEnabled() -> MyProtocol {
        return self.filter("type == 1").filter { $0.enabled == true }
    }
}
```

XCode gives me this error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'filter'`. I think `T:MyProtocol` constraint is not enough.

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is not the generic constraint, but that both `filter` methods, you're using here return a collection, which doesn't match the return type you specified.

That's also important to note: The first filter you apply can be optimized internally by Realm to query your database, the latter is part of the Swift standard library and pulls all objects into memory first before filtering them.

```
extension Results where T: Named {
    func firstEnabled() -> Named? {
        return self.filter("type == 1 && enabled == true").first
    }

    func filterEnabled() -> Results<T> {
        return self.filter("type == 1 && enabled == true")
    }
}
```

Comment: I was doing a much more complicated filter on the second part. Just simplified it for the question. Thanks anyway. Fixing the return type didn't fix the error. Another error was `$0` didn't have an `enabled` property. Both had to be fixed to fix the "much less related" error message. XCode should first give me "$0 didn't have enabled", and after that "return type doesn't match"

Comment: Oh okay, makes sene. Just wanted to be sure that you're aware of the implications. In such cases, it often helps to hint the Swift compiler by splitting down the expression and declare explicit types, but that can be tedious.

Comment: Yes it is tedious. Hope they will fix these someday